# Use emit to return null

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, fastmember

I've been using the FastMember project. It contains this code:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 2); 
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) }));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
```

I would like to change that to just return null instead. I tried replacing it with a single line `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);`. However, I get invalid program errors using that. How do I set the return value to null using emitted code?

Comment: From a simple test program I notice you also have to use `ldnull` before returning it. Have you done so? (IL is stackbased, you have to add something to the stack so you can return it)

Comment: Almost any question in the form of "How do I do `x` in IL" can be answered with "write a simple C# program doing `x`, and use ildasm to look at the compiled IL".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just emit `ret`, that's like `return;` in C#. But you need `return null;`

You should use

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```